# Laravel API - updateOrCreate

Tags: laravel

I'm using the `updateOrCreate` for storing the data from my dynamic field. The update works but I'm having an error when adding a new row.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->rows as $row) {
      $db = Book::updateOrCreate(['id' => $row['id']]);
      $db->author_id = $request->author_id;
      $db->publisher_id = $request->publisher_id;
      $db->title = $row['title'];
      $db->genre = $row['genre'];
      $db->save();
    }
  }
```

I tried this method but now it doesn't work for both update and create.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->rows as $row) {
      $db = Book::updateOrCreate(
      ['id' => $row['id'],
      [
        'title' => $row['title'];
      ]
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Error message 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The errors shows that your routes didnt accept POST method.. change it to POST method

Comment: Your edited post made it work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **updateOrCreate**
>
> You may also come across situations where you want to update an
> existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides
> an updateOrCreate method to do this in one step. Like the
> firstOrCreate method, updateOrCreate persists the model, so there's no
> need to call save():
>
> **updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])**

Its should be like this. But make sure you have fillable in model

Option1

```
//Option 1
foreach($request->rows as $row) {
    $db = Book::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => $row['id'] ?? null
        ],
        [
            'author_id' => $request->author_id,
            'publisher_id' => $request->publisher_id,
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'genre' => $row['genre']
        ]
    );
}
```

Options2

```
// Options 2
foreach($request->rows as $row) {
    $input = [
         'author_id' => $request->author_id,
         'publisher_id' => $request->publisher_id,
         'title' => $row['title'],
         'genre' => $row['genre']
    ];
    if (isset($row['id'])) {
        if($db = Book::find($row['id'])) {
            $db->update($input);
            continue;
        }
    }

    Book::create($input);
}
```

**EDIT:**

The errors shows that your routes didnt accept POST method.. change it to POST method

Ex:
`Route::post()` instead of `Route::get()`

Comment: The error is weird. I'm still having a 500 error for both options when adding news row, but update works.

Comment: Both of the option is now working, thank you very much! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

> updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])

**Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.**

So your parameters is not correct. It needs two array parameters, not one array.
Check this out: [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->rows as $row) {
      $db = Book::updateOrCreate(
      ['id' => $row['id']],
      [
        'title' => $row['title']
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The error is weird. I'm still having a 500 error. If I remove `['id' => $row['id']]` the error is gone, creating new row works but then updating also creates another data.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you used the Models in your controller

```
use App\ExampleModel;
```

write the protected fillable fields in your model like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title','genre', ...
    ];
```

Comment: All checked. Thank you!